# simple trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

how would you solve this

$$\cos^2 x - 2\sin x \cos x - \sin^2 x = 0$$

I tried to simplify it but I got $\cos 2x - \sin 2x$. I can't simplify that further.

Comment: Why are there two "sin squared x" terms? Don't they cancel out? Could you use Latex to type it out properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have reached.

$$\begin{align}(\cos 2x - \sin 2x)^2 = 0  &\Rightarrow 2\sin2x\cos2x = 1 \Rightarrow \sin 4x = 1 \\ &\Rightarrow x = \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi k}{2},\  k \in \mathbb{Z}\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that \begin{align*} [\cos(2x) - \sin(2x)]^2 & = \cos^2(2x) - 2\sin(2x)\cos(2x) + \sin^2(2x)\\ & = 1 - 2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)\\ & = 1 - \sin(4x)\end{align*}  As you can check, $\pi/4$ does not satisfy the given equation.

Comment: I missed $1$, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you have done,

\begin{align*}
\cos^2x - 2\sin x\cos x - \sin^2x & = 0\\
\cos^2x - \sin^2x - 2\sin x\cos x & = 0\\
\cos(2x) - \sin(2x) & = 0\\
\cos(2x) & = \sin(2x)\\
1 & = \tan(2x)
\end{align*}

Observe that if you want values of $x$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ that satisfy the equation, then $0 \leq 2x < 4\pi$.  Thus, we must find values of $2x$ in the interval $[0, 4\pi)$ such that $\tan(2x) = 1$.  They are

\begin{align*}
2x & = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{9\pi}{4}, \frac{13\pi}{4}\\
x & = \frac{\pi}{8}, \frac{5\pi}{8}, \frac{9\pi}{8}, \frac{13\pi}{8}
\end{align*}

Since $\tan(2x)$ has period $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, the general solution is

$$x = \frac{\pi}{8} + n\frac{\pi}{2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\cos2x-\sin2x=0$, or in other words, $\cos2x = \sin2x$. Where on the unit circle are the cosine and sine the same? That's the value of $2x$.

Comment: Cosx = sinx at 45 and 225 degrees. I dont know when cos2x and sin2x are equal.

Comment: Observe that if $0^\circ \leq 2x < 720^\circ$, then $0 \leq x < 360^\circ$.  Find all values of $2x$ in the interval $[0, 720^\circ)$ such that $\cos(2x) = \sin(2x)$, then solve for $x$.

Comment: Try putting a = 2x. Then you have to find where 
cos a = sin a
Then substitute that back into a = 2x and solve for x.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}(\cos 2x-\sin 2x)=0 & \implies\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos 2x-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin 2x=0\\&\implies \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-2x\right)=0\end{align}$.